# Saving multiple CSS value in an <option> element using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have some banners with different height and width and I want to save their values using a `<option>` element, when you select the size of your banner it will change the css to an element using `ng-style` I don't know how to do that and I hope you guys can help me to solve this.

I leave my code below:

```
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="banner1">120x600</option>
    <option value="banner2">160x600</option>
    <option value="banner3">300x600</option>
    <option value="banner4">300x250</option>
    <option value="banner5">336x280</option>
    <option value="banner6">250x250</option>
    <option value="banner7">250x200</option>
    <option value="banner8">480x60</option>
    <option value="banner9">728x90</option>
    <option value="banner10">970x90</option>
</select>
```

Element to apply the css:

```
<div class="chat_banner">
    <br />

    <figure class="chat_banner_img">
        <img src="images/jamie.png" alt="Jamie">
    </figure>

    <h2 class="chat_banner_header" ng-style="{ 'color' : bannerTittleColor }" >{{ banner.tittle }}</h2>
    <p class="chat_banner_des">{{ banner.description }}</p>

    <div class="chat_banner_btn">
        <p ng-style="{ 'background-color' : buttonColor, color: buttonTextColor }" onclick="goToChat()">{{ banner.buttonTxt }}</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.chat_banner
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #008FD1 0%, #233D62 100%);
    width: 336px;
    height: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You to save with ng-model in your select the selected value.

```
<select ng-model="bannerSelected" name="" id="">
```

So in your ng-style use your model

```
<p ng-style="{ 'background-color' : bannerSelected.bgColor, color: bannerSelected.color }" onclick="goToChat()">{{ banner.buttonTxt }}</p>
```

I suppose that you have correct value for your select options

Comment: I haven't set the value, in adition the ng-style must be applied to the banner if I really want to change de size, regards.